# How to make widget in body scrollable when using custom appbar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

used custom app bars but when i call them before a method in body including a ListView.builder() in it, they blocks ListView.builder to scroll. I want to show custom app bar and scrolling of ListView.builder.

i declared two methods separately for custom app bars and a method for body. And wrapped them in Listview which didnt work, tried to put the container in column and then wrap in ListView, then used Column and declared all as children of column.

```
final topAppBar = 
    Container(
      height: divheight/2*0.1,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
           children: <Widget>[
          Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
           child: Text("tRADING SOLUTION",
           textAlign: TextAlign.left,
           style: TextStyle(
             color: Colors.white,
             fontSize: 15,
             fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
           ),
           ), 
           ), 

           ],
         ),
         Column(
           //check container widget
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
           children: <Widget>[
             Container(
               height: 12,
             ),
          Container(
            padding:EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child:  Text("pOWERED BY fLEXI aNALYSIS",
           textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
           style: TextStyle(
             color: Colors.white,
             fontSize: 10,
             fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
             fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
           ),
           ), 
           ),


          ],
         ),
],
      ),

    );
    final customAppBar = Container(
      height: divheight/2*0.15,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
           children: <Widget>[
          Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.white,),
        ),
           ],
         ),
         Column(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
           children: <Widget>[
             Container(
               height: 7,
             ),
          Container(
            padding:EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child:  Text("Technical Analysis",
           textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
           style: TextStyle(
             color: Colors.white,
             fontSize: 20,
             fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
             fontStyle: FontStyle.normal
           ),
           ), 
           ),

        ],
         ),
         Container(
           padding:EdgeInsets.only(left: 100.0),
          child: 
          IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.list),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        )
      ],
      ),      
    );

final makeBody = 
Expanded(
      //decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0)),
      child: 
        ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: lessons.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        //get the data from db here through method
        return makeCard(lessons[index]);
        //makeCard(lessons[index]);      
        },
      ),
);

ListView _makeBody() =>ListView(
children: <Widget>[
    topAppBar,
    customAppBar,
    makeBody,
],
);

Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
        body: _makeBody(),
);
```

Comment: what is `divheight`?

Comment: @anmol.majhail var divheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

Comment: i changed your List view to Column - Code Worked- `Column _makeBody() => Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      topAppBar,
      customAppBar,
      makeBody,
    ],
  );`

Comment: @anmol.majhail thanx, design is a bit distrubed but its working!